# Vue + Webpack alias dynamic image src from ~asset folder

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to have a dynamic image src from the Vue data using Webpack alias.

In order to access to the right folder using `~assets/` in html or in css, I added an assets alias to my webpack config.

**Webpack config**

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    ...
    'assets': resolve('src/assets')
    ...
},
```

**Vue data**

```
data: {
  ...
  img: 'name-of-my-image.jpg',
  ...
}
```

**Html**

```
<img :src="'~assets/' + img"> // Does not work
```

`~assets/` works perfectly with regular src images `<img src="~assets/...">` or with CSS images `url('~assets/...')`

How can I use `~assets/` with `:src` and with  `data` from Vue?

Comment: At the network tab of DevTools, what request do you see, then vue sets value of "src" and it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Webpack is replacing the src value by an ID

Comment: Anybody has a solution for this trouble ????

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an alternate way**

Add this code in your methods

```
    getImgUrl(img) 
    {
            return '~assets/' + img
    }
```

On your template call like this

```
 <img :src="getImgUrl(img)">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. Your function is the same as doing `<img :src="'~assets/'  + img">`. In fact, webpack is modifying the src url before compiling and the data from Vue are used just after. So, no choice that using static image urls such as `.././assets/my-image.jpg`

Comment: no you set an alias for your custom path to anything you want in the vue.config.js file in the chainWebpack section: `config.resolve.alias.set('@assets', path.resolve('assets', 'some-sub-dir) // helper for vue file support`

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that returns the path by resolving the image URL with the help of `require`

**Method:**

```
    getImage(image) {
        return require("Images/" + image);
    }
```

Here "Images" is an alias defined in webpack config.

**Template:**

```
img(:src="getImage('imageName.jpg')")
```